# minhur bootstrap toggle does not show full width in modal, but does everywhere else

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-switch

I am wanting to use [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) plugin, but it does not show as expected in the modal for longer text. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/105/)

[image]

Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle-checkbox" checked>
$("[name='toggle-checkbox']").bootstrapToggle({
   on: 'Enabled',
   off: 'Disabled'
});
```

There is another plugin called [Bootstrap Switch](http://bootstrapswitch.com/), which produces desired result.

[image]

But the second plugin uses a lot more real estate, hence I am wanting to get the first one to work.
JSFiddle of both plugins: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/105/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the button is getting a wrong width value inside the expected modal.

Just wrap the input with a div and specify a custom CSS class to that div. Then you can easily select the toggle and style it via CSS so the width of 94px remains.

Keep in mind that everything what should appear next to the button has to be inside that div as well now. Or you could of course also customize the new toggling class as you like.

HTML:

```
<div class="toggling">
  <input type="checkbox" name="toggle-checkbox" checked>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toggling > .toggle {
  width: 94px !important
}
```

**UPDATE**

Another option and probably the better one is to simply set the width via a data attribute as the API docs suggest.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle-checkbox" checked data-width=94>
```

Now you don't even have to deal with custom CSS classes.

Comment: I saw the width solution here: https://github.com/minhur/bootstrap-toggle/issues/30 but is there not a way for it to figure the width out dynamically?

Comment: Therefore you could use the first version and set the width dynamically via JavaScript (for example 20% percent of of the outer modal width). See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beysv5b3/

Comment: I mean dynamic width as in automatically accommodate  "Enabled" or "A very long toggle text".

Answer (score 0):

There is probably problem with calculation width on hidden elements.
My workaround is to destroy toggle and reinit it by calling `bootstrapToggle()` every time modal is to be opened.

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myToggle').bootstrapToggle('destroy');
  $('#myToggle').bootstrapToggle({ .. options ..});
})
```

Hope this is working for modal also, I have tested it only for bootstrap tab-pane, where is similar problem.